# cronjobs.batch is forbidden on a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes administration. While trying to list & setup new cronjobs, one of the users is getting the following error:

> Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User
>    cannot list cronjobs.batch in the namespace

The role while creating this user:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: <user>
  name: <user>-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

The role binding while creating this user:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: <user>-role-binding
  namespace: <user>
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: <user>
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: <user>-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

What could the issue possibly be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Cronjob` resource belongs to the [`batch` API group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch).

In your RBAC role, you have only granted access to the `core` (empty name), `extensions` and `apps` API groups.

To enable your user to access CronJob objects, add the `batch` API group to your RBAC role:

```yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: <user>
  name: <user>-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps", "batch"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```